# Adding sparkline to the table with dates

Tags: r, formattable, gt

I have a table like below. I am grouping data by "name" and counting the records for each name. I want to add a sparkling using the "date" column to the table but haven't come across any documentation how to do that. I read about formattable R package but for that dates have to be in columns. I'll appreciate any help!

```
id name date
1 John 2018-05-30
2 John 2018-06-14
3 John 2018-06-15
4 John 2018-07-01
5 Miley 2018-01-01
6 Miley 2019-06-21
7 Miley 2020-05-19
```

This is how I am grouping. I now want to add another column to the table with the sparkline. This produce a sparkling but doesn't show name in the table

```
project %>%
  filter(date>= today() - days(14)) %>%
  group_by(week = week(date), name) %>%
  summarize(value=mean(n())) %>%
  summarize(
    `name` = spk_chr(value),
  ) %>% 
  formattable() %>% 
  as.datatable() %>%
  spk_add_deps()
```

Comment: This feels like something you want to do/achieve. Please note that you need some values for the sparkline to show. What is the variable in your data that reflects this?

Comment: count should have the values by name. Basically my idea is to plot a sparkling to show weekly average of the ids by name.

Answer (score 0):

`{sparkline}`  works well with "long format" data. Re-check the documentation you studied on how to prepare the data for it to work.

The latter comment also applies to your operations. The `group_by()` and `mean(n())` operation you perform feels odd. If you have a measurement (aka value) on every day (for each entity), you will obviously get a flat line ~ as you sum (or count) with `n()` 7 days per week.
Also make sure that you understand what `today() - days(14)` does seeing that the example dates are in 2018.

Your data example is, thus we generate an example data set (similar) to yours by "hijacking" iris for some values and plugging dates to it.

Check the data structure before supplying it turning it into a `sparkline` and be clear on what the column-names and variable-names of your desired output are, and where the "payload" for the sparkline (or other form) comes from.

**simulate data**

```
library(dplyr)      # data crunching
library(lubridate)  # for handling of dates

##---------- for the creation of a sequence of dates define a start-date
start_date <- lubridate::ymd("2018-05-01")

##---------- grab iris and truncate to Species for name, and value
df <- as_tibble(iris) %>% 
   transmute(name = Species, value = Sepal.Length) %>% 

##----------  add a date sequence to the data
##----------  for this we bin the data and assign a date based on the row index (using row_number())

   group_by(name) %>% 
   mutate(date = start_date + days(row_number()))
```

This gives us:

```
df
# A tibble: 150 x 3
# Groups:   name [3]
   name   value date      
   <fct>  <dbl> <date>    
 1 setosa   5.1 2018-05-02
 2 setosa   4.9 2018-05-03
 3 setosa   4.7 2018-05-04
 4 setosa   4.6 2018-05-05
 5 setosa   5   2018-05-06
 6 setosa   5.4 2018-05-07
 7 setosa   4.6 2018-05-08
 8 setosa   5   2018-05-09
 9 setosa   4.4 2018-05-10
10 setosa   4.9 2018-05-11
```

Check the data structure of this data frame. There is an entity column (name), the date, and associated measurement values for your data.

Please note that this data is in long format, i.e. dates are in a column!

**use long format to add sparkline to formattable**

With reproducible data example, let's go back to your problem.

Reshape the data sticking to the long format.
You group by multiple variables. Unless you specify it, `summarise()` will only drop the last grouping variable. The way you grouped, the df is still grouped by week after the summarise.

Take-away: unless you perform further grouped data operations, drop the grouping!

```
df <- df %>% 
   group_by(week = week(date), name) %>%
   summarize(    value = mean(value)     # with mean(n()) you only counts the days - which might what you want to do
             , .groups = "drop")         # deliberately drop the grouping, or use %>% ungroup()
```

Similar to above, we now have a - summarised - data frame in long format.

Data structure: week, value, and name.

The following creates the `html-character-representation` of the sparkline.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise("value change over time" = spk_chr(value))

## which returns the following
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name       `value change over time`                                                                                               
  <fct>      <html>                                                                                                                 
1 setosa     "<span id=\"htmlwidget-a4f3654304d9ef58957e\" class=\"sparkline html-widget\"></span>\n<script type=\"application/json~
2 versicolor "<span id=\"htmlwidget-af4f2905e298d6ddc412\" class=\"sparkline html-widget\"></span>\n<script type=\"application/json~
3 virginica  "<span id=\"htmlwidget-93ad2727bfe914386fa9\" class=\"sparkline html-widget\"></span>\n<script type=\"application/json~
```

Note: This time we group only over 1 variable (i.e. `summarise()` will drop the grouping completely).
Further more the operation creates "our" table idea: a column with the entity name and a column with the sparkline code.

The final bit is to inject this summarised table into `formattable()` and convert the `html representation` into a visual.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise("value change over time" = spk_chr(value)) %>%
  
##------- plug this into formattable
  formattable() %>%

##------- convert html into visual
  as.datatable() %>%
  spk_add_deps()
```

This yields:
[image: snapshot of formattable with sparkline column]

In short:

- keep your data in long format - that is no issue for sparkline
- be sure when and what to bin to reshape your data
- check the columns that you supply to your sparkline (what is the value, what the name(d) group, and how you name your sparkline column